# Did Aunt Marguerite kill Belle’s mother?

Tags: beauty-and-the-beast

Ok, so for those who didn’t know, there were 2 original screenplays for the animated *Beauty and the Beast*. The first had Beauty’s wicked sisters. The second one condensed the sisters into one character: Aunt Marguerite. She moved into Belle’s mansion to look after the family after Belle’s mother died. Given that she was like a wicked stepmother and she was obsessed with getting wealth and power, is there any evidence to suggest she killed Belle’s mother?

Comment: There were in fact 3 earlier scripts, not 2.

Comment: Really? What plot did the 3rd screenplay follow?

Comment: Dunno, Disney rejected it immediately as being "too dark" and "glum".

Comment: https://ohmy.disney.com/insider/2016/01/03/the-beauty-and-the-beast-that-almost-was/

Answer (score 4):

The showreel for the [Richard Purdum](https://ohmy.disney.com/insider/2016/01/03/the-beauty-and-the-beast-that-almost-was/) version of the script (produced for Disney's approval) strongly implies that Maurice's sister, the loathsome Marguerite, simply decided to come and freeload off of him.

**There's no strong indication that she murdered his wife, not least because her death seems to have taken place some considerable time *prior* to Marguerite's arrival.**

Comment: Well, there’s a theory that says that Lady Tremaine killed Cinderella’s mother so she could marry her father. So if that theory’s true, why can’t the Marguerite killing Belle’s mother be true?

Comment: @AlexDowns - Sure, it could be true. Anything *could* be true.